# Open instead of prompt for download XML Documents on IE (Link emailed from a SPD WF)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, internet-explorer

i have a workflow that sends an email with the link to the current document (an infopath form with xml extension) so my users can go to the document directly from that email. The problem is when some user has IE as default browser and click that link IE prompt for download the xml file instead of just open it as an infopath form (as does Chrome or Firefox).

I am using the action 'email' of Sharepoint Designer 2010 and lookup 'Workflow context:Current item URL'. Its result is something like: `http://server/site/list/document1234566.xml`.

Some guess?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to tweak the workflow URL to look like this:

```
http://server/site/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XmlLocation=http://server/site/list/document1234566.xml&DefaultItemOpen=1&ClientInstalled=true
```

This should force SharePoint to open the XML either in InfoPath Forms Service or client InfoPath.

Comment: That Worked! I just built the link with that structure in the hyperlink maker of the mail popup and voila! Thank you very much.